# How to expand vectors or matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

While I am studying Linear Algebra, I come across equations like $$\lvert\lvert x_1a_1-x_2a_2-b\rvert\rvert^2$$ or $$(b-Ax)(b-Ax)^T$$ or $$\lvert\lvert{Ax}\rvert\rvert^2 = x^TA^TAx$$ However, I am not able to expand all of the equations correctly. I tried expanding them like normal variables but there are several concerns; I am not sure whether the dimensions are appropriate or when the sequence would matter especially when the sizes of the matrix or vectors are not given. For instance, if A is a $m\times n$ matrix and $b$ is a $n \times 1$ vector, then $A\cdot b^T$ would not be valid but $A\cdot b$ would be alright. Similarly, if there are two matrices, $A$ and $B$, then $AB$ and $BA$ would make a difference. Hence, I hope the community could provide me a link or a medium where I can access and learn about the expansion and simplification rules.

Comment: The only things you need to know are:

1. $\|x\|^2 = x^Tx$,
2. $(a+b)^T=a^T+b^T$,
3. $(ab)^T=b^Ta^T$,
4. $a(b+c)=ab+ac$,
5. $(a+b)c=ac+bc$.

Apply these rules repeatedly and you can simplify all your examples.

Comment: You need to be very careful about preserving the order in which things are multiplied as you do this. Changing the order can result in the sort of size mismatches that you mention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general you should not "expand" such expressions into component until (and unless!) you have concrete values for the variables and want to evaluate them to a numeric result.

---

However, you can do something like
$$ \begin{align}
(b-Ax)(b-Ax)^T
&= (b-Ax)(b^T-(Ax)^T) \\
&= (b-Ax)(b^T-x^TA^T) \\
&= bb^T - bx^TA^T - Axb^T + Axx^TA^T
\end{align}$$
though $(b-Ax)(b-Ax)^T$ would be a somewhat strange thing to do in the first place -- it looks like it is probably a typo for $(b-Ax)^T(b-Ax)$ which would expand to
$$ b^Tb - b^TAx - x^TA^Tb + x^TA^TAx $$
and then, since $x^TA^Tb = (b^TAx)^T$ and -- assuming that $b$ and $x$ are column vectors -- it is an $1\times 1$ matrix which is its own transpose, we could further collapse it to
$$ b^Tb - 2b^TAx + x^TA^TAx $$
Only do anything like this if you have a good reason to, though -- in general the $(b-Ax)^T(b-Ax)$ form is what you'll want to be working with.